# Strange behaviour of PHP mail()

Tags: php, email, email-headers, roundcube

I am using php `mail()` to send email from my website. But I am facing strange behaviour.

```
  $headers  = "From: Saurabh Sharma <no-reply@example.com>\r\n";
  $headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Return-Path: me@example.com\r\n";
  $headers .= "Organization: Saurabh Sharma\r\n";
  $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP\n";
  $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\n";
  $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
```

But all the mails are landing in spam.

Also, I have added a rule on the server to send the copy of every mail to my personal email on gmail. I am able to receive the mail on gmail when I use php `mail()` (in spam) but can't see any mail on RoundCube on my server even if the receiving address is of my domain email address i.e `me@example.com` but I receive only the copy on gmail.

Also, If I send mails to/from Roundcube to my Gmail and vice versa, mail always lands in inbox in Gmail and Roundcube also shows the mail in inbox.

But strange things are happening in php `mail();`

The major issue is that email is not received on me@example.com but I can see the copy on Gmail.

Am I doing something wrong in headers?

Comment: Do you have an mx record that authenticates your webserver to send mails for `example.com`?

Comment: gmail has checked the `from` mail id and if it's not a registered gmail id then everything goes to spam.   check these links:-  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935087/how-do-i-prevent-mails-sent-through-php-mail-from-going-to-spam   and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16352112/how-to-prevent-mail-from-going-to-spam

Comment: @Anant If I use Roundcube itself, The mails are received on gmail without any hassle.

Comment: @SaurabhSharma  check the links that i have given to you. it will help you. Also some of non-gmail id's also worked(we can not list domains which will worked)

Comment: What about the 'reply to' that looks like a different email

Comment: @Forbs Same code works fine on my other application on other server.

Comment: @Anant The issue is not that emails are landing in spam, but why I am not receiving mail on my server and instead I am only receiving a copy on Gmail

Comment: take a look at the headers of the 'good' emails and see what's different,  I know you said you set the MX record, but it's how anti-spam sees if a server can send emails, i suspect your MX record is setup wrong.